# How to update data using modal with ajax, php and mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to update data using modal with ajax in PHP. I am beginer, plz tell me where is my mistake .

HTML Code

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  data-toggle="modal"  data-cphone='.$row['country_phon'].' data-cname='.$row['country_name'].' >Update</button>';
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

     <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Update Country</h4>
            </div>
    <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <input type="text" id="cn"  name="pcountry">
      </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <input type="text" id="cph" name="pphone">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary updt" name="updatecountry" >Save</button>
```

JS Code: Here when I click on Button, modal appears with the values fetched from database with the help of jquery.

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){     
    var cphone =$(this).data('cphone');   
    var cname =  $(this).data('cname');
    $("#cph").val(cphone);
      $("#cn").val(cname);
      $("#myModal").modal('show');   
     });
     });</script>
```

JS code : This is ajax code . I want to update the text of textbox.

```
            <script>
                $(".updt").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();                     
                    var cnt = $("#myModal").find("input[name='pcountry']").val();
                    var cp = $("#myModal").find("input[name='pphone']").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type:'POST',
                        url: 'test.php',
                         data:{pcountry:cnt, pphone:cp},
                    })

                  )};

                </script></div>
```

PHP Code :

```
                          <?php 
if(isset($_POST['updatecountry']))
{$country1 = $_POST['pcountry'];
$phone1 =   $_POST['pphone'];
echo $country1;
echo $phone1;
echo "Updated Successfully";
 mysqli_query($conn,"update country set country_name='$country1' ,   country_phon='$phone1' where country_id=18");
 mysqli_close($conn);   

 }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On view `btn` class use for `update` and `save`. I suggest you please use different class name or id.

```
<button type="submit" class="form_update btn btn-success"  data-toggle="modal"  data-cphone='.$row['country_phon'].' data-cname='.$row['country_name'].' >Update</button>';
```

JS changes

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".form_update").click(function(){     
            var cphone = $(this).attr("data-phone");   
            var cname = $(this).attr("data-cname");
            $("#cph").val(cphone);
            $("#cn").val(cname);
            $("#myModal").modal('show');   
       });
   });
</script>
```

Hope this code is workinf fine.